# How to update dependencies when trying to use Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, dependencies, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Android development, so in order to implement Firebase Authentication I'm using a book ("Firebase Essentials Android Edition"). I follow the instructions to use Email/Password authentication and it works, however, when I update

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

the methods to sign out and delete account stop working, even though I still can build the APK. How do I fix this?
My gradle.build settings are

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doov.firetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.firebase:firebase-auth` is a transitive dependency of `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth` and does not need to be listed in your `build.gradle` dependencies.  Having it in your dependencies creates potential version conflicts.  The [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) describes the transitive dependency relationships and provides a table of compatible versions. `firebase-auth:11.0.4` is not the correct version for `firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1`.

Delete this line from your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

This allows `firebase-ui-auth:x.x.x` to include the correct version of `firebase-auth`.

Also, if you only need the auth capabilities of FirebaseUI, include only that library, not all of FirebaseUI with `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:x.x.x`:

```
//compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1' // <== not needed for only Auth
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
```

One more change is needed. `firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1` for some reason has a transitive dependency on `firebase-core:9.0`.  This seems like a bug.  It is the source of the `Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb` error noted in the comments.  Add this line to force inclusion of the correct version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
```

Comment: When I delete that line and build the APK I get the next error:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb;

PD: When I use the original (version 11.0.1) the build works and signout and delete account both work. When I change to 11.0.4, the APK is still built, but signout and delete don't work.

Comment: @LucianoFalco: Make the change, then do a Clean, and try rebuilding again.

Comment: I deleted the line, used Build->Clean Project, Build->Rebuild project, then built the APK, but I get the same error.

Comment: @LucianoFalco: See my updated answer.  Add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'`

Comment: My app uses google maps, when I add it I get 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
(I updated the build.gradles to reflect this and your suggested changes). But now the project doesnt build. I get the error
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.1.

Comment: @LucianoFalco:  Build versions with FirebaseUI and Firebase require special care.  They must be the same and compatible.  Review the FirebaseUI docs at the link I included in my answer. If you want to use 11.0.4 of google maps, you must use 11.0.4 of `firebase-core` and 2.2.0 of FirebaseUI.  You will also need to use the correct version of `appcompat-v7`, which I think it is 25.4.0.